# Трекер сна с API

Tags: api

> Понимаю что вопрос очень общий, но постарался его более конкретизировать, так-же скорее всего такого протокола нет и возможно есть реверс инженерия некоторых трекеров сна.

Есть протокол для трекеров сна по которым можно выбрать браслет для мониторинга сна, допустим при засыпании или пробуждении вызывать события?

---

На данный момент очень интересны характеристики Xiaomi Mi Band, но не нашел информации информации как можно читать данный с браслета.

Comment: в поисковике можно найти различные попытки обратного проектирования протокола взаимодействия с браслетом. попробуйте их.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, я видел статьи про  Mi Band v1 и есть осушения что прийдется тоже делать для v1.5 или v2 и есть шанс закинуть этот браслет в черный ящик, но спасибо за ответ.